# SSL implemation

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-alb

So, i know we can enable SSL on the AWS Application load balancers. But the set up here is, the connections terminates on an on-prem f5 loadbalancer. The traffic is then routed to an internal(private) application load balancer in AWS.

Can i still enable the SSL by load the certs in the ALB or do i have to enable it in the F5.

Note: the webapp is an internal application and is not accessible from the internet

Comment: i need ssl (even for an internal site) - to enable sso with Azure

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: No - i am still waiting for the ssl cert . Things move slow here